# Anyone knows how to install davfs2 on a free (vps.me) vps server?

Tags: vps, davfs2

Our security regulations requires me to save logs outside the vps server. I need to install davfs2. The following procedure works on my laptop but not at an Ubuntu 13.04 server from vps.me

```
:~# apt-get install davfs2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  davfs2
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Need to get 145 kB of archives.
After this operation, 492 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe davfs2 amd64 1.4.6-1ubuntu3 [145 kB]
Fetched 145 kB in 0s (208 kB/s)
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76, <> line 1.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package davfs2.
(Reading database ... 37451 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking davfs2 (from .../davfs2_1.4.6-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Setting up davfs2 (1.4.6-1ubuntu3) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline

:~# mkdir -p /mnt/WebDAV
:~# mount -t davfs https://<my-dav-server> /mnt/WebDAV
Please enter the username to authenticate with server
https://<my-dav-server> or hit enter for none.
  Username: <my-username>
Please enter the password to authenticate user <my-username>@<my-dav-server> with server
https://<my-dav-server> or hit enter for none.
  Password:  
p11-kit: couldn't open config file: /root/.pkcs11/pkcs11.conf: Permission denied
/sbin/mount.davfs: can't open fuse device
/sbin/mount.davfs: trying coda kernel file system
/sbin/mount.davfs: no free coda device to mount
root@dxspider:~# libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:505 kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file: could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab083.2/modules.builtin.bin'
FATAL: Module fuse not found.
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:505 kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file: could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab083.2/modules.builtin.bin'
FATAL: Module coda not found.
```

I guess

Comment: You can't use FUSE filesystems on OpenVZ based containers unless the host has specifically set up the host environment to allow for it. Contact your hosting provider, or use real virtualization technology (not OpenVZ).

Answer (score 3):

For a user, not. davfs2 is a usermode filesystem, and thus its mounting required root privileges.

But if you have root privileges, but don't have the required knowledge, I suggest to ask somebody for the job.

The real meaning of the message of the support is the following: "We don't do anything for you, because we know, that you will further and further asks and questions after that, and probably you won't ever pay for it. But we also won't make a hating ex-customer from you, thus we write this meaningless nothing to you. You can try this davfs2 install for your responsibility, if you want, but it will be from this point not our problem. We clearly see, that you are absolutely unable to do this for yourself - maybe after 2-3 years of sysadm experience it will be better for you. Until that, we can't teach you - first, we aren't teacher, second, because you probably won't ever pay for it."